# Do I have to sanitize and or validate post data server side if using SSL with a mobile app?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, ssl

I'm building a mobile app that posts data to a server via ajax post, which is processed server side by PHP that ultimately performs mySQL database manipulation.  I know with web apps it is important to sanitize and validate data to avoid security issues, but i"m wondering if it necessary in a closed source mobile iPhone or android app that conducts the transactions via SSL?  Would the post data be accessible and would it be subject to malicious manipulation?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, unless you're using SSL to validate client certificates — and honestly, even then. You're still talking to clients over the *internet*; you shouldn't assume that the source of the data has no malicious intent.

Comment: He says he IS using SSL, although that doesn't really change the answer.

Comment: @Porco just because it's SSL doesn't mean you're validating the client. In fact, hardly anyone ever does. The qualifier wasn't *if you're using SSL*, it was *if you're validating client certs*.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but why and how would you validate client certs? Never heard of that practice (and to think, I added SSL for our web apps)

Comment: @Porco you have to create and sign SSL certificates, and distribute them to the clients in some secure manner, and then configure your server to verify that the cert the client presents is trusted (i.e. signed by you). It can then pass the information about the client's identity to your app. The reason it's not widely used is because it's difficult to distribute and install the certs on clients in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

ANYTHING that comes from the client is vulnerable to "malicious manipulation", SSL does not protect you from this.

Answer (score 1):

You should always sanitize your data! However, I disagree on the part that extra security doesn't do any harm, especially on mobile devices.

You should get it straight on what type of data is going to be inserted, an take adequate measures to secure it. If you get to be paranoid with it, and take precautions that aren't absolutely need you'll get yourself an overkill and compromise processing speed which, is not that much on mobile devices yet...

Comment: I assume he is talking about server side validation, so mobile processing speed would not be an issue.